# Как получить определенное количество связных объектов из бд?

Tags: python, django

models.py:

```
class Section(MPTTModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table='Section'
    section_text = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название раздела', max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(verbose_name='Родительский Раздел',to='self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

class Question(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Question' 
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    question_text = models.CharField(verbose_name='Описание вопроса', max_length=250)
```

views.py:

```
sections = Section.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2,3])
questions = Question.objects.filter(section__in=sections)
```

В questions получаю все вопросы связанные с разделами.

Как получить не все вопросы, а определенное количество вопросов из каждого раздела?

Например из раздела c id=1, получить 5 вопросов ,из раздела c id=2, получить 6 вопросов, из раздела c id=3, получить 7 вопросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понял с чем у вас сложности. Но зачем усложнять, когда можно сделать простым способом?

```
questions = []
for id, number  in {1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7}.items(): 
    questions.extend(Question.objects.filter(section_id=id)[:number])
```